# Руководство по Enterprise Java Beans

Tags: java, jsp, ejb

Прочитал несколько статей по этому поводу, но так и не пришло понимания в каком порядке нужно все ставить и как связывать компоненты системы. Есть какие-нибудь руководства по подъему серверов приложений и связи базы данных с ними?

UPD1. Разобрался немного в теме. Надо начинать с [JAVA EE 6 Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/).

UPD2. Все заработало, но понял что лучше было бы не начинать :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инструкция по настройке зависит от сервера приложений. Например, если у вас glassfish, то для связи с базой нужно настроить пул соединений. Например, [так](http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/08/06/creating-and-configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-glassfish-application-server/).

Что же до EJB, то это вообще никак не связано с БД. По началу лучше пока не трогать эту технологию, пока нет понимания и базовых знаний о JavaEE, о работе приложений и веб-контейнера.